# Debug macro vs. Debug variable

Tags: c++, debugging, macros

Below is an example of using a debug variable

```
class A{
 public:
  A(bool debug):m_debug(debug){};
  ~A(){};

  void Test(){
    for(int i=0;i<1000000;i++){
      // do something

      if(m_debug) print();
    }
  }

  void print(){
    std::cout << "something" << std::endl;
  }


 private:
  bool m_debug;
};
```

Below is an example of using a debug macro preprocessor

```
#include "Preprocessor.h"

class A{
 public:
  void Test(){
    for(int i=0;i<1000000;i++){
      // do something

#ifdef DEBUG
        print();
#endif
    }
  }

  void print(){
    std::cout << "something" << std::endl;
  }
};
```

In Preprocessor.h is simply

```
#define DEBUG
```

The good thing about using a debug variable is the class has one less dependency on a global preprocessor header. The good thing about the macro approach is that there are 1000000 less if statement executed at run time, which might be critical for lets say graphics application when every single fps counts. What would be considered as a better approach?

Comment: In this case the use of preprocessor

Comment: If the `do_something` contains more than an if-statement, the tests will likely be negligible. With a variable you also have the option to turn debug on and off during the execution.

Comment: This is not an advantage. You build a debug version  (I. Ed.  Able to use debugger erc) and a release version (smaller and quicker).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The better approach is to use preprocessor, however, it do not necessary a new header file to define the macro.

You can set the flag at compiling, using `-DMACRO_NAME` or, in your case, `-DDEBUG`.

Comment: Or whatever the appropriate command line syntax is for the OP's compiler.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the job is printing debug info, the precedent is to use macros like Visual Studio does (debug/release build). However in Qt world, there is class `QLoggingCatagory` where you can enable/disable logging sections. It calls the function `QLoggingCategory::isDebugEnabled()`every time a message is being logged out which makes me think it is not a major issue for performance at least for normal use.

That said if we comapare Visual Studio MFC application with Qt application, MFC applications are lighting fast. This could be attributed at least in part because it uses macros and the difference can be noticed rather easily in debug and release build as well where macro/debug info is the main difference.

Given all this evidence my vote is for macros approach in your case for maximum performance.

Comment: I was also wondering whether using a debug macro is premature micro optimization, but looks like it actually makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

First, the macro way is better for both benefits in memory and if testing(though this is really minor cost). Do you have any special scenarios to use the debug variable?

why not define the A::Test() in the CPP file? thus the global preprocessor header could be moved to the CPP file. Anyway, I don't think expose such debug details in the header is a good idea.

Comment: A::Test() should be in the CPP file in production code. I was trying to get the shortest code out for my question.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative, if you do not like having a bunch of #ifdef DEBUG / #endif lines, you could create a macro that outputs it's argument if defined (much like the assert macro).

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define PRINT(x) (x)
#else
#define PRINT(x)
#endif

PRINT( std::cout << "something" << std::endl );
```

Answer (score 0):

The code path does not get much more minimal than "compiled away". However, if you are willing to perform a refactoring step, you can make the run-time debug version cheaper at the cost of a larger executable.

The idea is to make the debug state a template parameter of a refactored version of `Test()` so that it may or may not print a debug statement on each iteration. The compiler's dead code elimination pass will then optimize away the statement in the case `false` is passed to the template, since template parameters will be treated as compile time constants in the template expansion.

The fully optimized version can still use conditional compilation to always disable debug output, of course.

```
template <bool Debug>
void TestDebug(){
  for(int i=0;i<1000000;i++){
    // do something
    if (Debug) print();
  }
}

void Test(){
#ifdef DEBUG
  if(m_debug) TestDebug<true>();
  else TestDebug<false>();
#else
  TestDebug<false>();
#endif
}
```